# Word 2010 Citation Manager: Edit inline citations?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I'm writing a document in Word 2010 using the citation manager. The document has several website sources, and a few are from the same website. Since these citations all have the same "corporate author," the citations all appear identical. How do I change the citations to be unique?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... i think you can put them as footnotes (the one with the little number).

And there you can put the sources you want to manage without repeat all the info.
 I hope is the thing you are asking!